# Does $p\left(\frac{Y_1+...Y_k}{k}>x-\frac{a}{k}\right)$ increase with $k$?

Tags: probability

$Y_i$ is a i.i.d. random variable following Bernoulli distribution with success probability of $\alpha$.

Then, does $p\left(\frac{Y_1+...Y_k}{k}>x-\frac{a}{k}\right)$  increase with $k$ for any given constant $x>0$? Note that $a>0$.

Comment: what is $x$ here?

Comment: @user12075 Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question. $x$ is a given constant.

Comment: Hint: use the Central Limit Theorem to estimate the probability.  If you want a more elementary approach, *still* use the CLT to guess the answer and then prove it using, say, Chebyshev's Inequality.

Answer (score 1):

No. It converges to either $0$ or $1$.

By the WLLN, the Left hand term converges in probability to $E[Y_i] = \alpha$.

On the other hand, the right hand side clearly converges to $x$ since $a/k \to 0$.

Hence if $x < \alpha$ the probability converges to $1$, but if $x > \alpha$ it converges to $0$.

So if $x < \alpha$ then it increases with $k$, but if $x > \alpha$ it decreases.

Comment: What if $x$ happens to be $E(Y_i)$?

Comment: Use the central limit theorem, the probability will converge to a constant.